# Can't Get Dialog to show programmatically in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-dialog

I'm trying to get a div with data-type 'dialog' to display in JQuery Mobile, fired by a Javascript event.  The button click in the example below is purely to fire the event.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //$.mobile.changePage('#addCatForm');

            $('#createEvent').click (function () {
                console.log('Prove event fired');

                $.mobile.changePage('#addCatForm', {
                    transition: 'pop',
                    changeHash: false,
                    role: 'dialog'
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
        <button id="createEvent">Create Event</button>
        <div data-role="dialog" id="addCatForm" data-theme="c">
            <p>here is some text</p>
            <div data-role="content">
                <input type="text" id="catText" data-theme="c"/>
                <input data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" type="submit" id="addCat" value="Add Category">

                <button data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" id="canCat">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

The console.log output correctly fires, but nothing I can do seems to get the dialog to display.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Put the `dialog` div outside the `data-role=page`. only popups can be inserted inside `data-role=page`. Treat it as a `page` but with `data-role=dialog` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Jx9xM/

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#createEvent').click (function () {
        console.log('Prove event fired');

        $.mobile.changePage('#addCatForm', {
            transition: 'pop',
            changeHash: true,
            role: 'dialog'
        });
    });
});
```

Dialog must be on a same level as a page and not a part of the page. I this case I have moved dialog outside of a page.

Comment: Accepting this answer because of the thorough jsfiddle.  Thank you both.

Comment: You should not use $(document).ready with jQM, you should use $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
  //apply overrides here
}); http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/

Answer (score 2):

Your structure should look like this, `data-role=dialog` outside `data-role=page`.

```
<!-- Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
 <button id="createEvent">Create Event</button>
</div> 
<!-- /Page -->

<!-- Dialog -->
<div data-role="dialog" id="addCatForm" data-theme="c">
 <p>here is some text</p>
 <div data-role="content">
  <input type="text" id="catText" data-theme="c"/>
  <input data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" type="submit" id="addCat" value="Add Category">
  <button data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" id="canCat">Cancel</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- /Dialog -->
```

Comment: Great answers to both Omar and @Gajotres.  Thank you - it works.  However, I've been trying to close this dialog and the  $('#addCatForm').dialog('close') function does not seem to behave as I would expect.  How do I close this dialog with access to its DOM elements?  Thank you.

Comment: @JonRed when you close it, it goes back to `#mainpage`?

Comment: if you want to go back to previous page add `data-rel="back"` attribute to `#addCatForm` div. @JonRed

Comment: When I run the $('#addCatForm').dialog('close') function, nothing happens at all.

Comment: Take a look at my example again :http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Jx9xM/ I have also changed changeHash: false to changeHash: true.

Comment: Thanks @Gajotres, I got it at the same time your comment came in.  It is in fact the changeHash property that was causing the problem.  I'd like to mark both answers as 'Accepted' ;-)